# How to run integration tests without Docker on version 7.9.3

Tags: docker

I have been using jHipster for quite a few years. The new requirement to setup and use Docker is making it very difficult for me to start a new project using version 7.9.3. Using a local installation of MySql server for my old projects and a Docker instance of MySql for new projects is just one issue.

Rolling back to a previous version is not a sustainable solution.

Is there a way to turn off this new requirement?